# jQgrid progressive data loading of grid?

Tags: jqgrid

I have huge set of data which is killing my browser. So wanted to try using progressive data loading. Not sure how will I be able to do that.

Can someone share if already done in jQgrid?

I already am making ajax call to get the data.

Comment: Could you include the code which you use? The most common case of hanging web browser is not because of "huge set of data". The common problem is that one fill the grid in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

in this link refer Autoloading data when scroll.
I think this is your solution